# Running first singleview ios application on Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm writing a very first program for iOS in Xcode 6 (Single-view application). 
I added a label and ran a simulation.

I have seen this label on a simulator. But when i added an additional button on a Main.storyboard's ViewControler and rebuilt the project - the was no any button. It seems like simulator ran first version without the button. How can i launch last version of my project on a simulator?

Thanks.

Comment: If your using size classes and put the button in the center of the storyboard without any layout guides. Chances is are the button is displaying off screen.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the build? (cmd+shift+K)

Comment: @antonio no it doesn't help. Simulation is running with a very first version of a project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 6 run by default with auto layout enabled along with size classes also enabled..

you can check that by disable both of them by going to your storyboard and show file inspector (you'll find it on the right side pane)

[image]

And then  rerun the app.. if you find the button in its place.. then you should start learn how to use the auto layout cause it's essential now by apple to support any universal app you wish to create in the future .

Comment: Thx a lot. It was not so simple as it seemthd to me

Comment: it's ok .. i've hit my head to a wall for hours when i hit it :)